# sql error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
Create table Login_User
(
    IDnum int foreign key references Contacts(ID),
    Username varchar (50),
    Password varchar (50), 
    SecretQ varchar(50),
    SecretA varchar (50),
)

Create procedure sp_create

    @Username varchar (50),
    @Password varchar (50), 
    @SecretQ varchar(50),
    @SecretA varchar (50)

as

insert into Login_User

Values (@Username, @Password, @SecretQ, @SecretA)
```

The error is when  I execute the stored procedure

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_create, Line 10
>   Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `IDnum` is the foreign key column, it can't be `NULL` or empty, until you have the `NULL` values in the `Contacts` table `ID` column.

Your query can work if the `IDnum` is the auto increment value, other wise you have to pass the `IDnum` value and store into the table.

So your actual query should be:

```
insert into Login_User (IDnum, Username, Password, SecretQ , SecretA )
Values (@IDNum, @Username, @Password, @SecretQ, @SecretA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create insert command by providing all the column list

```
insert into Login_User (Username, password, secretq, secreta)
Values (@Username, @Password, @SecretQ, @SecretA)
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It is now executable

Answer (score 0):

You have to also **include** IDnum column value in insert query:

```
insert into Login_User (IDnum, Username, Password, SecretQ , SecretA ) Values (@IDNum,@Username, @Password, @SecretQ, @SecretA)
```

**OR**

**Remove** IDnum from insert query:

```
insert into Login_User (Username, Password, SecretQ , SecretA ) Values (@Username, @Password, @SecretQ, @SecretA)
```